# Help with @a[scores={objective=1}]

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Long story short, me and a couple of my friends decided to make a server that we can play on because we were bored, and we wanted to add trails to our shop. The trails would work like so: every player that has *fogTrailEquipped* *= 1*, we display the particles on them. But for some reason my command doesnt work after I added the @a[scores={fogTrailEquipped=1}] part.
heres my command (on a repeating command block):
`execute at @a[scores={fogTrailEquipped=1}] run particle minecraft:ash ~ ~ ~ 0 0.5 0 70 70 normal`

Answer (score 2):

The command is functional, so check the following:

**Is the command block activated?**

Check that the command block is set to `Repeat` and `Unconditional`.

If it is activated by redstone, (`Needs Redstone`) make sure it is powered by a redstone input, such as a lever, redstone block, etc.

If it is set to `Always Active`, make sure that the command block did not glitch and stop activating. (This happens to me sometimes.) Change the setting to `Needs Redstone` and then back to `Always Active`. You can make sure it is activating if the time in `Previous Output` increases.

**Does the target player have the score?**

Type `/scoreboard objectives setdisplay sidebar fogTrailEquipped`. Any players that have a score will appear in the list. You can clear the sidebar later with `/scoreboard objectives setdisplay sidebar`.

**Is the scoreboard a dummy scoreboard?**

If the scoreboard is not a dummy scoreboard, you may have issues giving scores to players. Type `/scoreboard players set @s fogTrailEquipped 1`. If an error returns: "Scoreboard objective `fogTrailEquipped` is read-only", then you need to delete the scoreboard and recreate it:

```
/scoreboard objectives remove fogTrailEquipped
/scoreboard objectives add fogTrailEquipped dummy
```

**Is the command block loaded?**

Command blocks will not work if the chunk it is located in is unloaded. Chunks unload whenever a player is not nearby, so if the command block is far away this may be the reason. You can fix this issue by placing the command block in the [spawn chunks](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Spawn_chunk), which are never unloaded.

**Are your particles off?**

The particles will not be visible if you have your particle settings set to `Minimal`. You can fix this by changing the setting to `Decreased` or `All`, or you can change your command to show particles regardless of settings:

`execute at @a[scores={fogTrailEquipped=1}] run particle minecraft:ash ~ ~ ~ 0 0.5 0 70 70 force`

Answer (score 1):

The issue is not with your selector in your command, because it is correct according to the [wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Scoreboard#Objectives). You should check that the player you are trying to spawn the trail at actually has the score fogTrailEquipped set to 1.